# Perform multiple actions with 1 post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Being new to rails, I've implemented a blog in rails. Users with permission can comment on a blog. The admin has the possibility to also comment on the blog and also to lock the discussion. For this reason I want to implement a similar feature like the Github `Close and comment` function. The admin can comment on the ongoing discussion, can lock it or can command and lock it. These 3 actions are are done with 2 buttons.

I already implemented a client-side javascript function to toggle the button title from `Lock` to `Lock and Comment`. My problem now is that the blogpost and the discussion posts are associated to different controllers. Locking is performed within the `BlogController`. Discussion posts are handled with the `DiscussionController`.

How can I trigger 2 actions with 1 action:

1. Send the form the the `DiscussionController`
2. Lock the blog post in the `BlogController`

Currently I've separated the actions. Creating a new post us done by `form.submit` which is connected to `DiscussionController`. Locking the discussion is done by `link_to` the `BlogController`.

How can I combine these 2 actions?

Comment: More info is needed. Maybe add some more code. Also it appears you have some typos which make the question confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without seeing some example code to get a clearer picture of what you're trying to accomplish, but it sounds like a great candidate for encapsulation.

That is, create a plain old ruby class inside your `models` directory that handles both locking AND commenting.  Then, inside one of your controllers, create a new instance of that class and perform some method on it.

The idea is to keep things simple by making sure your controllers don't have to work too hard.  Essentially, you want to move most of your login into your model, but in this case because you are performing actions on TWO models you'll want your logic in an entirely seperate class.  This is in order to prevent one of your models from becoming super powerful and taking over the world.  (Just kidding, we're just trying to avoid a bad programming pattern called a [God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)).  There's another best practice called the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which further justifies creating a new class for this.

For example,

```
# /app/models/lock_and_comment.rb
class LockAndComment
  def initialize(discussion, comment_params, user)
    @blog = discussion.blog    # Assumes discussion belongs to blog
    @discussion = discussion
    @comment_params = comment_params
    @user = user
  end

  attr_reader :blog, :discussion, :comment

  def lock_and_comment!
    @blog.class.transaction do
      comment = @discussion.comments.build(comment_params)
      comment.user = @user
      comment.save    # You may even want to put this and the above two lines in a seperate method and call it from here
      @blog.lock!    # Assuming .lock is defined in blog model
    end
  end
end
```

The initialize block is going to get you set up with the `.new` method.  Then, call `.lock_and_comment!`.  `@blog.class.transaction` ensures that the if there is a problem with either commenting on the discussion or locking the blog, neither one happens.  Here's an example of what that might look like in your controller:

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  # POST /blog/:id/lock_and_comment, as an example route
  def lock_and_comment
    @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
    closing_comment = LockAndComment.new(@discussion, comment_params, current_user)    # Assumes current_user is a user

    if closing_comment.lock_and_comment!
      redirect_to @discussion, notice: 'Locked and commented!'
    else
      redirect_to :back, alert: 'There was an error!'
    end
  end
end
```

This also assumes you're locking the blog from a method inside your model.  If you're performing the logic in your `BlogsController`, you should probably go ahead and move it into your mode.  "Fat model, skinny controller" is what they say.  It will also improve the readability of your controller.  That way, your normal locking method would look like:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def lock
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    if @blog.lock!
      # do some things, etc etc etc
    else
      # process error
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your Blog model:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def lock!
    self.locked = true
    self.save
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.  That's how I would approach this.